# Collection does not return object on first() method

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have a code where I'm trying to get the first Object of eloquent collection  objects with the "first()" method, but I'm getting a "trying to get property of non-object exception".

If I loop the collection with a foreach, there is no problem accessing the properties of each object.
But when I try to access the properties of the first record that I'm trying to get via "first()" method (I don't mind which object of the collection really), then I get that, what is returned, is not an object.

```
$movimientos = 
            Om_movimiento::with(['estado_om',
                                'om' => function($query)
                                        {
                                            $query- >with('legajo','legajo_cuadrilla','terminal.armario.central','tipo_trabajo_om');
                                        }])
                          ->where('id_om', '=', $request->get('id_om'))
                          ->orderBy('created_at','asc')
                          ->get();

    
        foreach($movimientos as $m)
        {
            echo $m->fecha_movimiento;
        } //->no error here
    
        echo $movimientos->first()->fecha_movimiento; //->error trying to get "fecha_movimiento" property.
```

Am I missing something here?

Comment: Could it be that in the first case, you needed just the first record. You could have then just changed `->get()` to `->first()`

Comment: I get it, but if I needed all the records, and I just want to get any of them, but just one, and after the get(), what whould be the best way?

Comment: Could you dd($movimientos) please?

Comment: I think that $movimientos might be an array rather than a collection of objects, which is why you wouldn't be able to use `->fecha_movimiento`

Comment: Ooooohhhh I didnt know this dd() stuff... Im retrieving nothing from database, thank you!!

Comment: @user10341554 Post it as an answer so I can mark it, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot access `first()` on `$movimientos` because it currently isn't returning a collection from the database. You can debug using a variable dump `var_dump()` (http://php.net/manual/en/function.var-dump.php) or die dump `dd()`.